# Mypy has trouble loading plugin in vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, plugins, mypy

In the same virtual environment I installed mypy and pandera and pandera's mypy plugin.

```bash
pip install mypy
pip install pandera
pip install pandera[mypy]
```

Added in my `setup.cfg`

```yaml
[mypy]
plugins = pandera.mypy
```

Mypy vscode extension (`matangover.mypy` ) is installed.

In *global* `settings.json` I got

```py
"python.venvPath": "D:/miniconda3/envs",
"python.terminal.activateEnvInCurrentTerminal": true,
"python.terminal.activateEnvironment": true,
```

In my workspace's `settings.json`

```py
"python.defaultInterpreterPath": "D:/miniconda3/envs/my-workspace-venv/python.exe"
"python.linting.mypyPath": "mypy",
```

VScode does activate my virtual environment upon start-up, no problem.

But still mypy complains in it's vscode output tab:

```
Error importing plugin "pandera.mypy": No module named 'pandera'
```

While python doesn't complains when I import it in vscode *integrated terminal*:

```py
python -c 'from pandera import mypy'
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally got things working if I launch *VScode* from terminal with the virtual environment activated.

I remember Having an issue with ssh agent not forwarding keys in *Remote - WSL* and launching vscode from wsl bash terminal was the solution to that issue as well.